# Longest-ever time between problem posing and solving?

Tags: math-history, open-problem

Guiness World Record [claims](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/longest-standing-maths-problem-(current)) that Goldbach's conjecture is the oldest unsolved problem. A natural related question is what solved problem went unsolved for the longest time. In other words, of all the now-solved problems, which was open for the longest?

Perhaps it depends how we define the moment when a problem becomes "posed," but we could define this moment as the first time the problem is referenced in any record we have.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem must be a contender at the very least. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem), it was posed around 1637, and proven in 1994, making a 357-ish year gap between statement and proof.

Comment: Some would say the "odd perfect number problem" is older than Goldbach. The independence of the parallel postulate, although it wasn't posed that way, is another problem with roots in antiquity, solved in the 19th century.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What proof of conjecture in number theory might be striking for you?I am very curious about your opinition... I can say Collatz for myself.

Comment: @lone, the ABC-conjecture. Also, Schanuel's conjecture. And of course the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Thank you for answer. I only read two of what you said...By the way, I guess Collatz doesn't seem interesting to you..

Comment: @lone, it's very interesting, but the three I mentioned have in common that their resolution would have far-reaching implications. Lots of other results depend on them. That's not as true for Collatz, twin primes, Goldbach, etc.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Thank you for your comment.!I am glad to learn your opinition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some geometric construction problems - e.g. [doubling the cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube) - were "posed" in antiquity but only solved in the $19$th century. This gets us a gap of about $\sim 2000$ years at least.

Re: the scare quotes above, there is a slight issue here about what exactly constitutes *posing* a problem. The texts I'm aware of all phrase it as a **positive imperative**, "figure out how to double the cube using only compass and straightedge." Since the punchline is that that can't be done, there's a disconnect between the way the problem *was* posed and the way it *should have been* posed. I personally think this still counts though.

Comment: Similarly for the parallel postulate. For centuries, the goal was to prove it followed from Euclid's other postulates. Then it turned out it was independent of the others.

Comment: I think it still counts, too. The problem was "solved" by showing it couldn't be done, even though the ancient greeks might not have expected that possibility.

Comment: I'm going to add, since I just found here, that ancient Indian mathematicians seem to have posed the problem of squaring the circle somewhere in the period 700–400 BCE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_mathematics#Śulba_Sūtras

Comment: Or at least, it sounds like they considered the problem and attempted to solve it and wrote about it. Again one could debate whether this counts as "posing" the problem, but it certainly counts for something.